# Making a cumsum created vector correspond to the data from which it was created.

Tags: r

I am using `cumsum` to calculate the accumulation of thermal units (tu).  Each day has multiple thermal units, so then I end up with a vector that has a length of over 3000, but I what I want is another column in my dataframe that tells me how many accumulated thermal units I have each day.  Here is an example dataframe:

```
doy  tu
1    5
2    10
3    5
4    5
5    10
6    5
```

and what I want it to look like:

```
doy  tu  cumtu
1    5   5
2    10  15
3    5   20
4    5   25
5    10  35
6    5   40
```

I have been using `cumsum(df$tu)`, but am not sure how to use `cumsum` in the context of my df.

Comment: `df$cumtu <- cumsum(df$tu)`

Comment: Thanks, @SimonO101! I thought I had tried that, but turns out I had messed up my df name in the code.  It is, of course, perfect.